# group permissions in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, groups

Can read and write permissions be assigned to groups so that users in those groups will inherit the same properties. If yes, how to assign read permission to specific group.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/118258) for further guidance.

Comment: Some programmers are reluctant server admins.  For example, I am, and I wanted to know how to assign group permissions such as "log on as batch user" - this answer seems like it's in a similar category - I encourage users to re-open this for serverfault.

Answer (score 3):

> Can read and write permissions will be assigned to groups so that
>   users in those groups will inherit the same properties.

Yes.

> if yes how to assign read permission to specific group.

It is done exactly how you would manage permissions for individual users.